# React how to route to external link

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react. I have the folowing code:
const CompanyCard = ({name, address, postcode, companyUrl}: company) => {
const handleViewEmployees = (name: string) => {
console.log(name);
}

```
const openInNewTab = (url: string) => {
    const newWindow = window.open(url, '_blank', 'noopener,noreferrer')
    if (newWindow) newWindow.opener = null
}

return (
    <>
    <td>{name}</td>
    <td>{address}</td>
    <td>{postcode}</td>
    <td><a href="#" onClick={() => openInNewTab(companyUrl)}>{companyUrl}</a></td>
    <td><button onClick={() => handleViewEmployees(name)}>View Employees</button></td>
    </>
)
```

}

export default CompanyCard;

I want to open the company url in new tab. ie. the url 'www.google.com'. currently it is opening prepending `localhost:3000/www.google.com`

Answer (score 0):

```
const openInNewTab = (url: string, shouldOpenNewTab: boolean = true) =>
shouldOpenNewTab ? window.open(url, "_blank") : window.location.href = url;
```

Try out this

Answer (score 0):

You should add the protocol to the URL. So add either `https://` or `http://` at the beginning of your URL.

```
window.open(`https://${url}`, '_blank', 'noopener,noreferrer')
```